# How Sync android galley when capture a new image which save to custom folder

Tags: android, android-camera, gallery

i implements an app which capture image and save them to my custom folder. everything is OK but the problem is, my gallery don't get sync when i capture image. it means gallery don't show new capture image. for that i need to reboot my phone.

Here is my image capture code....

```
if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                BaseColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED};
        final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
        final String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " > " + time;
        Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, u,
                projection, selection, null, imageOrderBy);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        if (null != cursor && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
            cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    BaseColumns._ID + "=" + cursor.getString(3), null);
        }
        //showing image in image view
        cameraPicture = output.getPath();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cameraPicture, options);
        binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        binding.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

> **so how can i sync my android galley when i capture the image??? so that i can view this image immediately from galley.**

Comment: There is nothing in your question that involves "capture image and save them to my custom folder".

Comment: sorry for that i am new and it was my first question. so i don't know how to post a question and stackoverflow showing me error. so copy my onresult code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need notify system after saving file

```
 private void scanFile(String path) {

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this,
            new String[] { path }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Finished scanning " + path);
                }
            });
}
```